# Can't select an option from a dropdown menu

Tags: java, html, selenium, phantomjs

I am new to selenium. I am getting lot's of trouble selecting elements from dropdown menues. I am implementing it using PhantomJS - same code working using Firefox as Webdriver won't work using PhantomJS. I need to develop the code using PhantomJS to run it on a VM.

Env setting {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"windows-7-32bit","selenium version":"3.0.1  2016-10-18"}

Here is what I tried and did not work:

- Get the "Select" object and use the available methods(selectByVisibleText - selectByIndex - selectByValue) - {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"}
- Click on the dropdown menu and than click on the element (tried different By types and different HTML attributes: div - input - select -->  )
- Get all the available options from the "Select" object (getOptions) and click on the desired element {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"}
- Send the text directly to the "Select" object (sendKeys) {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"}

None of those methods - some found here on stackoverflow - worked for me. Please help me find a solution; hope that this question may be useful for others as well.

Thanks in advance!

Example code 1:

```
Select dropdownAvailableAverageDroveKM = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel_percorrenza")));
dropdownAvailableAverageDroveKM.selectByIndex(1);
```

Example code 2:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='10.000 - 20.000']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-value='01']")).click();
```

Example code 3:

```
Select dropdownAvailableAverageDroveKM = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel_percorrenza")));
List<WebElement> percorrenze = dropdownAvailableAverageDroveKM.getOptions();
for (int i = 0; i < percorrenze.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 2) {
        percorrenze.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Example code 4:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("sel_percorrenza")).sendKeys("0 - 10.000");
```

Here the HTML:

```
<div class="selectContainer select-wrapper required invalid">
   <span class="material-icons caret">arrow_drop_down</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown ipt-sel_percorrenza valid" data-activates="select-options-6e6bc713-38a9-6d84-6d1d-4f98ac98a935" value="10.000 - 20.000" readonly="" data-search-options="false" placeholder="" aria-invalid="false">
   <ul id="select-options-6e6bc713-38a9-6d84-6d1d-4f98ac98a935" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 269px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
      <li class="active" data-value=""><span>Seleziona</span></li>
      <li class="" data-value="01"><span>0 - 10.000</span></li>
      <li class="" data-value="02"><span>10.000 - 20.000</span></li>
      <li class="" data-value="03"><span>20.000 - 30.000</span></li>
      <li class="" data-value="04"><span>oltre 30.000</span></li>
   </ul>
   <select name="oggettoAssicuratoModel.veicolo.percorrenza" class="required initialized invalid" id="sel_percorrenza" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
      <option value="">Seleziona</option>
      <option value="01">0 - 10.000</option>
      <option value="02" selected="selected">10.000 - 20.000</option>
      <option value="03">20.000 - 30.000</option>
      <option value="04">oltre 30.000</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For exception, you need to set windows size:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768)); // fake browser to do something on GUI
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'sel_percorrenza')]")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("0 - 10.000");
```

Hope this will help you